# Swift: UINavigationBar seems light compare with UIView with same colour

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

I just try to set the same colour through `Attribute Inspector` to the `Navigation Bar` and the `Status Bar` But the `Navigation Bar` seems light in colour compare to the `Status Bar`. Check the Image.

[image]

And how to set the proper Navigation Bar for all devices.

Comment: Has color that you're using set opacity to 100%?

Comment: I checked that and I think that's all okay.

Answer (score 0):

You have to uncheck translucent option from attribute inspector. Then the color is matched with status bar and navigation bar.